# Hidden method invoked in negation

Tags: python

What method of b is invoked by python when i write `-b`? I suspect that it is `__sub__`, but I don't understand what happens when we have only variable (`b`). Is `0.__sub__(b)` executed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for negation [`__neg__`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.__neg__) operator:

> ```
> operator.neg(obj) 
> operator.__neg__(obj)
>
> Return obj negated (-obj).
> ```

Answer (score 2):

When the unary negation operator is used on an object, python calls its `__neg__` method.

Here is a simple example showing how you could use it and customize it even

```
>>> class B(int):
...     def __neg__(self):
...         return self*2
... 
>>> b = B(3)
>>> b
3
>>> -b
6
```